# Different functions conditional on previous page's link ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 a elements directed to the same URL, but whenever that URL loads, a different function must be carried out depending on the id of the a element which opened it.

Is this possible with Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.! But you should show some of your codes.

Comment: There's no code yet, I'm asking hypothetically. But it should be 3 <a> elements directing to the same URL. On that URL there are 3 <div>s or <li>s. a different one of them should open depending on the id of the a link which the user clicked on in the previous page.

Comment: 'YES! it's possible', but you have to try before posting on stackoverflow my friend.

Comment: I always try, couldn't find an answer. It's hard to find keywords for such a question I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use hash for your purpose. I am not very clear about your requirement, but might help you

```
<a href="www.abc.com#test1" />
<a href="www.abc.com#test2" />
<a href="www.abc.com#test3" />
```

now after you page load in abc.com. In page load event you can do

```
if(location.hash == "#test1")
// do test1 work
else if(location.hash == "#test2")
// do test2 work
else if(location.hash == "#test3")
// do test3 work
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works great! You just need to insert the "#" inside each "test" string within the conditional statement. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Update it. If the answer helped you please select it as correct answer. I will help others also. Thank you.